# Remove first word from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, split

What's the best way to remove the first word from a string in Java?

If I have

`String originalString = "This is a string";`

I want to remove the first word from it and in effect form two strings -

```
removedWord = "This"
originalString = "is a string;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple.

```
 String o = "This is a string";
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(o.split(" ", 2)));
```

Output :

```
[This, is a string]
```

***EDIT:***

---

In line 2 below the values are stored in the `arr` array. Access them like normal arrays.

```
 String o = "This is a string";
 String [] arr = o.split(" ", 2);

 arr[0] // This
 arr[1] // is a string
```

Comment: Since the question is rather basic, you'll probably need to clarify how to get the first and second part of the string from the returned array.

Comment: Actually, I liked your first answer better. The println only makes it more vague.

Comment: I dont think that'll be necessary hehe. Just looking for the BEST way of doing this simple operation in Java, as you can see there have been a few differing answers.

Comment: @JohnMcDonald This is simple enough to me.

Comment: Use `\\s+` to view all white space after a "word" as word boundary (the definition of word and word boundary is where it gets tricky, e.g. you might want to include comma's in the mix too).

Comment: @Mob I didn't downvote because I think your solution is valid. However I understand the guy who did it. Indeed this answer is largely upvoted although it's probably the less efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `substring`

```
removedWord = originalString.substring(0,originalString.indexOf(' '));
originalString = originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf(' ')+1);
```

Answer (score 4):

This will definitely a good solution

```
    String originalString = "This is a string";
    originalString =originalString.replaceFirst("This ", "");
```

Comment: Not the case when you don't know what the first word is.

Comment: Or if there exists another word later on in the sentence

Answer (score 3):

Try this using an index var, I think it's quite efficient :

```
int spaceIdx = originalString.indexOf(" ");
String removedWord = originalString.substring(0,spaceIdx);
originalString = originalString.substring(spaceIdx);
```

Prior to JDK 1.7 using below method might be more efficient, especially if you are using long string (see this [article](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/)).

```
originalString = new String(originalString.substring(spaceIdx));
```

Answer (score 2):

For an immediate answer you can use this :

```
removeWord = originalString.substring(0,originalString.indexOf(' '));
originalString = originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check where is the first space character and seperate string.

```
String full = "Sample Text";
String cut;
int pointToCut = full.indexOf( ' ');

if ( offset > -1)
{
  cut = full.substring( space + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "This is a string";    

String str2=str.substring(str.indexOf(" "));
String str3=str.replaceFirst(str2, "");
```

String's [replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst) and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

also you can use this solution:

```
static String substringer(String inputString, String remove) {
    if (inputString.substring(0, remove.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(remove)) {
        return inputString.substring(remove.length()).trim();
    }
    else {
            return inputString.trim();
    }
}
```

Example : 
substringer("This is a string", "This");

Answer (score -1):

You can use the StringTokenizer class.