# How does removing the first word out of a scanned string sentence work with the Scanner class?

Tags: java, string, printing, java.util.scanner

**The assignment is:**

> Write a Java program that reads a sentence in one go as a String, and
> writes this sentence back to the screen without the first word. For
> instance:
>
> Give Your Sentence: The Great Gonzo
>
> Great Gonzo

Underneath is the code. But how does the scanner class remove the first word? I don't quite understand. If could give an explanation, or provide some resources as to how this code removes the first word, that'd be great. Thx a lot. Here's the code:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Geef je zin : ");
    String input = scan.nextLine();  //Input contains entire sentence
    System.out.println("\n" + input);
    scan.close();

    //butfirst
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(input);
    String word = scan2.next();
    String rest = scan2.nextLine();
    System.out.println("-> " + rest);
    scan2.close();

    //butsecond
    Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(input);
    word = scan3.next();
    String word2 = scan3.next();
    rest = scan3.nextLine();
    System.out.println("-> " + word + rest);
    scan3.close();
```

Comment: You can do this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378447/4207306

Comment: The code as shown doesn't follow the assignment, because it says to read the whole sentence in one go, but instead you're reading the first word, and then the remainder of the sentence.

Comment: Works as expected. A sample run: `Geef je zin : The Great Gonzo

The Great Gonzo
->  Great Gonzo
-> The Gonzo
` What is the problem?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash OP wants to know how the code works

Answer (score 0):

well, key is

```
String word = scan2.next();
```

it consumes the first word so next call `scan2.nextLine()` return everything except first word. Output from `scan2.next()` (first word) is actually useless, it is not used anywhere, it is called only to move "scanner internal pointer" by one word.

However there are, of course, much better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

next() reads input until it encounters the delimiter which is space ("") (by default, but I believe it can be changed)

nextLine() reads input until it encounters a new line (\n) or a 'ENTER'
and when your input is read the cursor is now at a new line

Ex:
input = "Geef je zin";
next() = "Geef" and the cursor would be at j, so calling nextLine() would give you "je zin" and the cursor would be at a new line

input = "Geef je zin";
nextLine() = "Geef je zin" reads the whole line

I'm not very good with explanations but there's a well written article on geeksforgeeks:
www. geeksforgeeks. org/ difference-between-next-and-nextline-methods-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`scan2.next()` moves the Scanner's internal "pointer" forward by one word up to the first space, and returns the word. `scan2.nextLine()` returns the rest of the line and moves the pointer to the next line. In the example, `|` represents the pointer:

```
scan.next():     The|Great Gonzo
                 returns first word

scan.nextLine(): The Great Gonzo
                 |
                 returns the rest of the line starting from the previous pointer position
```